# Configuring JMS Resources in GlassFish in CloudBees platform

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jms, cloudbees, paas

All

I have a Java EE 7, JMS application. I would like deploy it in GlassFish server of CloudBees Paas. But the resources like connection factory and destination need to be configured in GlassFish. In local host, these resources can be created either through the admin console of GlassFish or through the asadmin commands.

But how can I do this in CloudBees?

Thank you in advance.

Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudBees don't provide a Message Queue service you could configure on GlassFish, so using JMS don't really make sense in this context. For Messaging, you can use CloudAMQP partner and use the AMQP client.

Generally speaking, if you need to do some customization on glassfish stack, you can fork https://github.com/cloudbees-community/glassfish3-clickstack and change the configuration / add customization to glassfish.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. By the way, which Java EE features are supported by CloudBees? transaction, messaging, persistence? Thanks